# Zabbix measure nginx post request time

Tags: zabbix

What is the simplest way to have in zabbix upstream_response_time graph only for POST request.

upstream_response_time value is available in nginx access.log

Is there some way to extract upstream_response_time only for POST requests from access.log and draw graph in zabbix ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use log monitoring and make regexp to fit your needs.

Comment: Why down vote? Have you even tied zabbix log monitoring? It is perfect for this use case.